# Troubles with high notes

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I started taking singing lessons 1 year ago.

First I was recognized as a `baritono` and had a not so extended range, as far as I know, I gained 2 or 3 notes in the low part and moved from a `Fa4` to `Si4` in the high part. My teacher now says that probably I'm a `baritenore` with some problems to fix in high notes and that the improvement I made is "out of standard", like it usually takes 4 years more or less.

Maybe it's important to say that when I sing, I feel like I can even reach higher notes but I feel "stuck".

I want to make clear, I'm talking about `belting`. If I use `falsetto`, I can move much higher (as an example I can sing [Never Enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jZVsr7q-tE) high notes without even feeling tired or stressed).

Now, coming to the question, I'm looking for advices, because I'm stressed about the fact that when I sing notes from `Sol4` to `Si4` I progressively tend to lose resonance and control, or atleast the sound quality, like something in my throat isn't letting me do what I would like to, and I feel like I'm having some troubles in fixing that problem.

How can I stop feeling "stuck"?

Comment: Could you use the names of musical notes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note) instead of solfege? Moreover, 1 year of voice lessons is a good start but I would advice you to be patient, sing regularly and continue taking lessons. Your voice most probably will transform and change many times during your vocal studies.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're belting out high notes, you need to stop (I'm an ex-belter).  As you sing higher (and belt) you're automatically creating tension in your throat, which will stop you from creating resonance, you loose control over the note (and may sing sharp or flat instead of right on the note), you don't get any kind of good vocal quality and you can ruin your voice!

That said, I'd suggest voice lessons with a good teacher!  You can sing higher in head voice and still sound strong (trust me, I can hit "C" 1 octave higher than middle "c"  in head voice , with no strain and it's strong and resonant - and I'm not a baritone, I'm 2nd bass!)

Take voice lessons and learn to sing properly and you'll be able to sing higher better, but in the mean time, stop belting!